# It is an error occured in sql part while performing crud operations in android studio

Tags: java, sql, xml, android-studio, sql-delete

```
2021-06-27 10:21:35.255 11487-11487/com.example.studentinfodb E/SQLiteLog: (1) no such column: rollno in "SELECT * FROM student WHERE rollno='1'"
2021-06-27 10:21:35.257 11487-11487/com.example.studentinfodb E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.studentinfodb, PID: 11487
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: rollno (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM student WHERE rollno='1'
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:1045)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:652)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:590)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:61)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:46)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1545)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1484)
        at com.example.studentinfodb.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:76)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7448)
        at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1119)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7425)
        at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:810)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28305)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

Comment: So obviously table `student` doesn't have a column named `rollno` in the database you're connecting to. What is your question?

Answer (score 1):

Please check the database. There might be no column named rollno in student table. Change the column to correct one and this problem should be resolved.

If the problem still exists then please share the code of entire code block instead of just error.